# How Can don't remember password in OBIEE 12c Login page without any configuration on browsers like Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: oracle, weblogic, business-intelligence, obiee

I'm using OBIEE 12c 12.2.1.3  and don't want to let browser saved password without any configuration on browsers like Firefox or Chrome.

Does any configuration on the weblogic application server to disallow password remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's the browser that does it. Hacking the page itself isn't a good idea.

Comment: Why? I try with "Autocomplete=OFF" but it doesn't work.